# To stop displaying of the frames in some jsp pages

Tags: html, jsp

I am using frames in jsp. I have included three frames in the starting jsp page.
I want those frames to appear only in the starting page. But those frames are appearing throughout the front end(in all the jsp pages).

I need to define different frames for different jsp pages.

can anyone pls help..

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: please post some code :)

Comment: Can you please attach screenshot so it will be easy to understand what actually you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using some Javascript and CSS. It would be easier if you are using a library like jQuery but you can do it without that.

Basically a quick way is to give the iframes a class / id and find them with JavaScript.

```
var myFrame = document.getElementByID("myFrame");
```

Then on each JSP add some logic to figure out which page it is and then you can either:

1. hide frames you don't want to show by setting the CSS display to none)
2. update the src attribute of the frame to be the correct one for this page

It depends on how many frames there are really.

So:

```
myFrame.css("display:none");
myFrame.src("newURL");
```